# Compiling error on Spec CPU06 benchmark soplex using gcc6.1

Tags: gcc, benchmarking

I am currently compiling the SPEC CPU06 benchmark using gcc 6.1. I got a compiling error on soplex. Two of several messages are as following:

> `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'int').`

I think I must have missed something while compiling but cannot find what exactly caused this. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your OS specifications. Note : You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time. Note 2 : If the "CPU06 benchmark soplex" is old, use an older compiler. "Issue 2011 of CPU06 benchmark" : Use e.g. gcc-4.4.x --- gcc-4.9 .

Comment: That's not two messages, that's part of one message.

Comment: Try `-std=gnu++98` or something.  Newer gcc might default to a newer C++ standard that breaks the benchmark.  Newer compiler versions *should* have backwards-compat options so they can still compile any obsolete code.  Newer versions of the C++ standard library might not be backwards-compatible, though.  IDK.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66771 (please use the G...)